# Llamadas fetch con URL por configuración

Tags: nodejs, express, url, configuración

Tengo una aplicación con NodeJS y Express. Creo un servidor con express() que me lanza una web `http://192.168.2.xx:3000` y además tiene varias rutas para atender Web Service POST y GET.

Actualmente en la llamada fetch para consumir los Web Service uso la URL tal cual:

```
fetch('http://192.168.2.xx:3000/Query' + '?id=' + username, {
    method: "GET"
})
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para no usar la URL de esta manera? Supongo que hay alguna forma de usarlo por configuración o averiguando la URL desde la que se llamó a la web.

Gracias.
Un saludo

Comment: `averiguando la url desde la que se llamo a la web.`  ¿A que te refieres con esto? Tener las urls ya definidas en algún sitio o como?

Comment: Hola, supongo que el código que pusiste es para solicitar datos desde el `front`? Si es asi, solo crea `const URL_BASE= (path)=> \`http://192.168.2.xx:3000/${path}\`` y solo llamas `URL_BASE('?id='+id)`

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi ya que expres puede recuperar parametros del url con `:` aqui la documentacion [documentacion](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

```
// capturamos el id enviado por la url
// ejemplo localhost:3000/id/22 o '/:id' para localhost:3000/22



app.get('/id/:id', function(req, res) {
  return titles.findOne({ id: req.params.id }, function (err, post) {
    if (err) { throw(err); }

    return res.render('titles', {title: post.title, url: post.URL});
  });
});
```